# Facebook opens "Ads Page" instead of regular homepage after login

Tags: facebook, login, account-management

My cousin who is a regular Facebook user has a problem with his Facebook account. I think he made something wrong which he does not remember and now he can't log in to his Facebook account properly. Whenever he enters his username and password using facebook.com, the following page opens directly:

http://www.facebook.com/advertising/

I looked over the settings and the links on that page, but couldn't manage to turn back to normal Facebook.

How can I revert his Facebook account to normal?

[image]

I've found [this thread](http://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1441697) which means some other users have the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is now solved after 3 weeks. I told my cousin to send Facebook (ip@facebook.com) an email explaining the problem in detail together with the screenshots. He did so and waited a few days without getting a reply. Then I told him to send the same email to Facebook various times. So he sent the same email twice a day to that address. There was still no reply or solution till yesterday. Finally, Facebook admins have sold the problem and now he can use his account.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer by someone on Facebook help center; thought to share it with you guys, maybe it is really working:

> 1. Log in to your account then go the Ads manager page https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/
> 2. From the right menu, click **Settings** then you can see Close Ads account. Chose **Other** and write account changed to Facebook ads by mistake then submit.

If you get "Account pending closure", just wait for a couple of minutes; if it not changed then hit close ads account again and repeat the whole thing till it says
"Your advertising account has been closed..."

After that you have to wait (in my case was 2 weeks) and it will automatically change back.

Comment: That did not work for our case...

Comment: When I visit https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/ it just directs me to my facebook business page and there's no ability to advertise. It's like I have the opposite problem from the OP.