# Facebook account that only redirects to Facebook for Business

Tags: facebook

I have a similar question to this one:

[Facebook opens "Ads Page" instead of regular homepage after login](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18740/facebook-opens-ads-page-instead-of-regular-homepage-after-login)

And I'm asking again because the solutions mentioned in that question no longer work.

A prospective client gave me access to his Facebook account, because he could not access a page he manages through it. I logged in, and was immediately redirected to the ads page::

https://www.facebook.com/advertising/

And then, immediately, it redirects to:

https://www.facebook.com/business/

If I paste an URL of any other FB profile, I see in the top blue bar just two links: "Configuration" and "Log out". In "Configuration" I see several options, but if I go to "Ads" (URL: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=ads), it just redirects me to FB for Business again.

The same thing happens, BTW, if I try to go to the "Support" link (URL: https://www.facebook.com/support/?ref=settings). It just redirects my to FB for Business again.

There isn't any link called "Close Ads account", as the answer in my linked question says.

So, how do I return this account to normal?

Comment: If this is substantially a duplicate of the other question, the thing to do is post a bounty to attract people to answer the question. It would also be helpful to point out the answers that no longer work (and vote them down!) If this _isn't_ a duplicate of the other question, you should [edit] this and make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your page id:
page id number: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

use this url with that number at the end

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```